# "Extract here" option doesn't work in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, archive, extract, rar

Extraction for rar/tar/gz files is working fine from CLI. In GUI, when right-clicking a file in Files app (both single and multiple parts archives) and choosing extract here in drop-down menu presents this message:

```
There was an error while extracting <<filename>>. Truncated RAR file data.
```

This was working fine in previous versions of Ubuntu (16.04, 18.04, 20.04, 21.04)

Comment: This rather sounds like a broken RAR file.

Comment: @vanadium, as I mentioned - works fine from CLI on multiple rar files.

Comment: @guiverc, gotcha - edited my question with the correct version numbers

Comment: Bust for me too. Clean install of 22.04 x64
R Click on a RAR file in the GUI, Extract Here errors with: There was an error while extracting "this.r03". Truncated RAR file data. If I open the same file R-click with: Other Application - Archive Manager it works.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I'll dig into it and potentially get a bug report made.